# Javascript property access speed: difference var.property vs. var["property"]?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a very basic JavaScript question.

I am writing a program which will generate JavaScript code. for accessing a property of a variable i have two choices:

```
1. make the property access a static query. i.e.
var result = object.property

OR

2. make the property access a dynamic query, i.e.
var result = object["property"]
```

The difference it makes to me is that for the first case (static query case) i will have to generate separate code for each property access. whereas in the second case (dynamic query case) i can reuse the same function for every property.

I can decide if i know does this makes any difference in performance?

is `obj.property` faster or `obj["property"]`?

May be this also depends on the engine which will be used to interpret javascript, so i must mention that I will be using Rhino as my javascript engine.

So please throw some light on this issue.

Thanks,
Regards,
VImal

Comment: They are both static, thus equal. Go for `object.property`.

Comment: if they are equal then i will go for object["property"] as it is beneficial for me.

Comment: @weima - Note that using `object["property"]` with a string literal will generate a JSLint error. It will advise you to use the `object.property` syntax. Also, any time you're concerned with the performance of some JavaScript snippets, you can use http://jsperf.com to test it yourself.

Comment: @weima how is that more beneficial? It's harder to write and read.

Comment: @Esailija as i am writing a program which will generate the code, if i generate code like `object["property"]` i can reuse the same code for many properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no static properties in Javascript, only dynamic property accessing exists.

Properties are always queried in the same way regardless of what syntax you put in your source code file.

Use jshint to recommend good source code conventions for your JS files:

http://jshint.com/

Dot notation is always recommended. Use quotation mark notation only if your Javascript property has not id which passes in JS syntax.

Comment: This is true on a theoretical level, but modern JS engines are smart enough to optimize static lookups to be essentially just a pointer operation. There's no difference between `object.property` and `object["property"]`, but both of those are faster than `object[variable]`.

Comment: If you use the google closure compiler in advanced mode, it is recommended to use the bracket variant (object["..."]). Properties will not be renamed then. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Answer (score 0):

Emphazise code reusability and maintainability. When you are done, and IF it runs slow, try to see WHERE it is running slow and better it.

So, is there any difference between `object.property` and `obj["property"]` in terms of eficciency? I don't think so, but mostly I don't think you should bother until you have encountered a performance issue with your finished, working code. This last part should be your worry.

And even if you find out that your code runs slow, I bet you this will NOT be the reason.

Comment: This is too generic answer to contribute anything useful to this particular, well-defined, question

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa there, I elaborated a little over my advice.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/testaccessobjectnotation/3 - Safari (JSC) still doesn't get with the program in 2014. The other implementations (V8, Monkey) seem to handle this identically which may imply the internal parse tree is the same in these latter implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I did this test on Node.JS

```
var obj = {test:"test"}

var time1 = new Date();
var t1 = time1.getTime();  

for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
  obj.test;
}

var time2 = new Date();
var t2 = time2.getTime();

console.log(t2-t1)

var time3 = new Date();
var t3 = time3.getTime();

for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
  obj["test"];
}

var time4 = new Date();
var t4 = time4.getTime();

console.log(t4-t3)
```

I find both perform almost the same, with `obj.test` performing a tiny bit better than `obj["test"]`

Comment: Don't purport "an irrelevant tiny bit" as a meaningful difference. In V8 (used in Node.js) there is no difference.

Comment: This is a helpful answer for those who are interested in marginal gains, and who don't know how to get simple insights into whether a difference may exist or not.