# What are the speed diferences between object's property access and normal variable access?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, properties

Before fully defining my question, I must say that >>[this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580448/javascript-property-access-speed-difference-var-property-vs-varproperty)<< doesn't answer my problem, and I have proven it to myself that the given answer doesn't match at all with the actual effect of property vs. variable or cached property (see below).

I have been using HTML5 canvas, and I write raw pixel blocks many times in a second in a 640x480 area.

As advised by some tutorials, it is good to cache the `.data` property of an `ImageData` variable (in this case, it would be  `_SCimgData`).

If I cache that property in  `SC_IMG_DATA`, I can  `putImageData` repeatedly in the Canvas with no problem; but if I repeatedly access it directly with  `_ScimgData.data`, the slow-down of the code is noticieable (taking nearly 1 second to fill a single 640x480 Canvas):

```
var SomeCanvas  = document.getElementById("SomeCanvas");
var SCContext   = SomeCanvas.getContext("2d");
var _SCimgData  = SomeCanvas.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 400);
var SC_IMG_DATA = _SCimgData.data;
```

---

---

---

**Now I have the following doubt:**

Would my code be as slow for other kinds of similar accesses?

I need an array of objects for a set of functions that can have several "instances" of an object (created by a regular utility function), and that need the index of the instance in an array of objects, either to create/initialize it, or to update its properties.

My concrete example is this:

```
var objArray=new Array();
var objArray[0]=new Object();
    objArray[0].property1="some string property";

for(var x=0; x<65536; x++)
 doSomething(objArray[0].property1, objIDX=0);
```

**Would that code become as unacceptably slow as in the Canvas case, if the properties and functions contained in some properties are called very intensively (several times in a single milisecond, of course using `setInterval` and several "timer threads" to avoid locking the browser)?**

**If so, what other alternative is there to speed up access for the different properties of several objects in the main object array?**

---

---

---

---

**EDIT 1 (2012-08-27)**

Thanks for the suggestions. I have up-voted them since I suspect they will be useful for the project I'm working on.

I am thinking in a combination of methods, using mainly `Array`s instead of `Object`s to build an actual array of "base objects", and addressing array elements by numbers (`arr[0]`) instead of string array keys (`arr["zero"]`).

```
var OBJECTS_SIZE=10
var Obj_Instances=new Array();
    Obj_Instances[0]="property or array 1 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[1]=new Array();
    Obj_Instances[1][0]=new ArrayBuffer(128);
    Obj_Instances[1][1]=new DataView(Obj_Instances[1][0]);
    Obj_Instances[2]="property or array 3 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[3]=function(){alert("some function here")};
    Obj_Instances[4]="property or array 5 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[5]="property or array 6 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[6]=3;
    Obj_Instances[7]="property or array 8 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[8]="property or array 9 of Object 0";
    Obj_Instances[9]="property or array 10 of Object 0";

    Obj_Instances[10]="property or array 1 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[11]=new Array();
    Obj_Instances[11][0]=new ArrayBuffer(128);
    Obj_Instances[11][1]=new DataView(Obj_Instances[11][0]);
    Obj_Instances[12]="property or array 3 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[13]=function(){alert("some function there")};
    Obj_Instances[14]="property or array 5 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[15]="property or array 6 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[16]=3;
    Obj_Instances[17]="property or array 8 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[18]="property or array 9 of Object 1";
    Obj_Instances[19]="property or array 10 of Object 1";

function do_Something_To_Property_Number_6(objIdx)
{
 //Fix the index to locate the base address
 //of the object instance:
 ///
   objIdx=(objIdx*OBJECTS_SIZE);
   Obj_instances[objIdx+6]++;   //Point to "Property" 6 of that object
}
```

I would have, say an "instance" of an "object" that takes up the first 10 array elements; the next "instance" would take the next 10 array elements, and so on (creating the initialization in a custom "constructor" function to add the new block of array elements).

I will also try to use jsPerf and JSHint to see which combination result better.

Comment: Another subtle enhancement (on top of what has already been mentioned) can be to use `x=65536;while(x--){doSomething(...);}` instead of a for... but only if it doesn't matter if your counter is travelling backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your "doubts", I suggest using [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to benchmark your code. One can't really tell by code alone if the procedure is *faster* than another unless tested.

Also, I suggest you use the literal notation for arrays and objects instead of the `new` notation during construction:

```
var objArray=[
    {
        property : 'some string property'
    }, {
        ...
    },
];
```

Also, based on your code, it's better to have this since you are using the same object per iteration:

```
var obj = objArray[0].property1,
    objIDX = 0;

for(var x=0; x<65536; x++){
    doSomething(obj,objIDX);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is not quite answering your question *(as it has already been answered)*, however as you seem to be looking for speed improvements in regard to function calls that happen thousands of times *(as others who find this might also be doing)*. I thought I'd include this here as it goes against assumptions:

An example function:

```
var go = function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) {
  return a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h;
}
```

The following is how you would normally call a repetitive function:

```
var i=500000; while(i--){
  go(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
}
```

However, if none *(or a few)* of those arguments ever change for this particular usage of the function, then it's far better to do this *(from a speed pov - obviously not an asynchronous pov)*:

```
var i=500000; go.args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
while(i--){
  go();
}
```

In order for the above to work you only need a slight modification to the original function:

```
var go = function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, i) {
  if ( go.args ) {
    i = go.args;
    a = i[0]; b = i[1];
    c = i[2]; d = i[3];
    e = i[4]; f = i[5];
    g = i[6]; h = i[7];
  }
  return a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h;
}
```

This second function runs significantly faster because you are not passing in any arguments *(a function called with no args is very quick to initiate)*. Pulling the values from the .args array doesn't seem to be that costly either *(unless you involve strings)*. Even if you update one or two of the args it's still far faster, which makes it perfect for pixel or imagedata manipulations because you are normally only shifting x & y:

```
var i=500000; go.args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
while(i--){
  go.args[2] = i;
  go();
}
```

So in a way this is an example of where an object property can be faster than local vars - if a little convoluted and off topic ;)

Answer (score 3):

Possible browser optimizations notwithstanding, accessing a property of an object is more expensive than accessing a local variable (but not necessarily a global variable or a variable of a parent function).

The deeper the property, the more of a performance hit you take. In other words,

```
for(var x=0; x<65536; x++) 
 doSomething(objArray[0].property1, objIDX=0);
```

would be improved by caching `objArray[0].property1`, and not repeatedly assigning to `objIDX`:

```
var prop = objArray[0].property1;
objIDX = 0;
for(var x=0; x<65536; x++) 
 doSomething(prop, 0);
```

Comment: Couldn't you also theoretically locally cache the `doSomething` function as a local var?